# Python/Numpy: Divide array

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data represented in a 1300x1341 matrix. I would like to split this matrix in several pieces (e.g. 9) so that I can loop over and process them. The data needs to stay ordered in the sense that x[0,1] stays below (or above if you like) x[0,0] and besides x[1,1].
Just like if you had imaged the data, you could draw 2 vertical and 2 horizontal lines over the image to illustrate the 9 parts.

If I use numpys reshape (eg. matrix.reshape(9,260,745) or any other combination of 9,260,745) it doesn't yield the required structure since the above mentioned ordering is lost...

Did I misunderstand the reshape method or can it be done this way?

What other pythonic/numpy way is there to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use `numpy.split()` which has its documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) ... or perhaps its sibling `numpy.array_split()` [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html).  They are for splitting an array into equal subsections without re-arranging the numbers like reshape does,

I haven't tested this but something like:

```
numpy.array_split(numpy.zeros((1300,1341)), 9)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This seems to do what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

reshape, to quote its [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html),

> Gives a new shape to an array without
>   changing its data.

In other words, it does not move the array's data around at all -- it just affects the array's *dimension*.  You, on the other hand, seem to require [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=slice#other-indexing-options); again quoting:

> It is possible to slice and stride
>   arrays to extract arrays of the same
>   number of dimensions, but of different
>   sizes than the original. The slicing
>   and striding works exactly the same
>   way it does for lists and tuples
>   except that they can be applied to
>   multiple dimensions as well.

So for example `thearray[0:260, 0:745]` is the "upper leftmost part, `thearray[260:520, 0:745]` the upper left-of-center part, and so forth.  You could have references to the various parts in a list (or dict with appropriate keys) to process them separately.

Comment: Slicing is of course always an option but I had a feeling numpy might have something on board for this purpose...